# is there possible to use nodemailer to auto change between different mail server to send mails?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm doing a mail modules which are using nodemailer. The problem I facing now is it possible to auto switch to different mail server to send out the mail. For example, like 4 mail server and each mail server limit to send out 20 mails and once mail server A reached 25 then it will switch to mail server B to continue the sending and so on.

I have try using for loop but seem like only finished the looping and send out the mails. I'm using windows 10, running nodejs and modules nodemailer as well.

...

```
for ( var i = 0; i < numberOfRecipients; i++ ) {
    if ( 
        ( i >= 0 && i <= 25 ) 
        || ( i >= 51 && i <= 75 ) 
    ) {
        // mail server configuration 1
    }
    else if ( 
        ( i >= 26 && i <= 50 ) 
        || ( i >= 76 && i <= 100 ) 
    ) {
        // mail server configuration 1
    }
}
```

...

I expect the output will be like can auto switch between different mail server and to continue the sending if the number we set per mail server can send is reached.

Comment: The way of accomplishing that aside. Would you explain why you have this limitation of 25? Asking to insure you aren’t trying to bypass the email reputation system or violating service agreement. As well as the spam side of things.

Comment: In the first place, why are you having a limit of 25 mail, seems like you are bypassing the system?